# Django + Ajax. Data submitted two times in database when I click on button at first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I use django for backend. Data submitted two times when I click button at first time and data submit one time when I clicked button second time and send response two time also. I am not know more about Jquery or Ajax.I need only one time data submit in database.

**views.py:**

```
@require_POST
def checkAns(request,pk,ans,user):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        question = Question.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if ans == question.answer_hidden:
            message = 'Correct'
            fetch_name = Register.objects.get(name=user)

            user_data = SubmitAnswer.objects.get_or_create(name=fetch_name)
            score_in = SubmitAnswer.objects.get(name=fetch_name)
            score_in.score += question.point      
            score_in.save()  
        else:
            message = "False"
            
    ctx = {'message': message}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx), content_type='application/json')
```

**question.html:**

```
**Other stuff like question,radio button,etc**
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="b1" onclick="getans()">click</button>
<p id="userans"></p>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#b1').on('click', function (e) {
        const id = document.getElementById('question_id').className
        const ans = document.getElementById('userans').innerText
        const user = document.getElementById('session').innerText

        $(".rb").show();
        $(".rb").attr("disabled", true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkAns/${id}/${ans}/${user}/`,
            data: { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                 console.log(response)
            },
            error: function (rs, e) {
                if(rs.status === 404){
                   alert("Please, Select Appropriate Option")
                }
                else{
                    alert("sorry, Something went wrong!!!")
                }
                
            }
        })
        });
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getans(e){
        document.getElementById("userans").innerHTML = "";
        var e = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
          for(i = 0; i<=e.length; i++){
              if(e[i].type == 'radio')
              {
                  if(e[i].checked){
                      document.getElementById("userans").innerHTML = e[i].value
                  }
              }
          }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Do `console.log` inside your event handler see how many that gets printed when you click on button.

Comment: @Swati Thanks to give answer.. Actually I put Ajax(jquery) CDN link in my base.html(Parent html page) instead of questions.html(child html). I don't know reason for this but it's solved my problem.